# IpTables -j REJECT to instantly block the loading on user browser

Tags: linux, networking, browser, firewall, iptables

I have been searching for a solution to notify the browser on user that the request is Rejected so stop loading it. Because I have blocked facebook and every page that have a facebook plugin is stacked at loading for 1 min, leading in confusion.

When I use this rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m iprange --src-range192.168.1.50-192.168.1.100 --dport 443 -j REJECT
```

I have to add this code `--reject-with tcp-reset` to do the request below, so the browser was noticed instantly for the rejection and didn't wait in loading any more.

Now my question is how can I do the same with this new rule I have added recently that block facebook using L7 information?

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "facebook.com" --algo bm --from 1 --to 600 -j REJECT
```

Comment: @emirjonb If the reject rule wasn't matched, then the browser would just go to Facebook, but you say it is hanging. Is it hanging becasue something else is blocking it and you want it to stop quicker?

Comment: @Paul Yes the connection is rejected but the browser doesn't notice it and stay on loading for more than 1 min. If you see the first example i mentioned this magic is done by `--reject-with tcp-reset` that i spend 2 months to find it :/

Comment: @emirjonb I think you missed my question.  Is the rule you have put in blocking it, or is something else.  Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: this rule is blocking it:iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "facebook.com" --algo bm --from 1 --to 600 -j REJECT...
The other is a example that achieve the same goal that i want for this rule, tell the browser not to wait

Comment: First understand how ip, tcp, and iptables work.  Then if you still want to use iptables, analyze this with wireshark.

Comment: Thanks @artistoex but as I explained and the language I am using seems that I know what am searching for

Comment: @emirjonb your approach fails for some reason.  But there is a chance to find out why, which is: methodical troubleshooting.  This is how you do it: compare the expected outcome with the actual outcome on every level.  Wireshark is a great tool for doing that.

Comment: @emirjonb So your iptables rule is actually blocking, and presumbably your REJECT list issues an RST packet. If your machine sees an RST it won't wait for a timeout.  I suspect that it is waiting for another session to finish.  We are going to need to look at a wireshark/tcpdump capture to know exactly what is going on.

Comment: ok have a look: http://i.imgur.com/HXEmzvM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

when you use iptables(netfilter), then you can't notify to browser. this blocking work on 4 level of OSI model, but you need level 7. i see solution in Squid proxy, who will redirect user browser to some url.

Comment: `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m iprange --src-range192.168.1.50-192.168.1.100 --dport 443 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`   > this rule make it perfectly, i just want the analog of this solution for the other rule. I have squid proxy but not filtering https traffic